# Implement Interpolation Polynomial Algorithm with Mathematica

Tags: recursion, wolfram-mathematica, interpolation, polynomial-math

I have to implement this algorithm in Mathematica:

[image: Algorithm]

My problem is that I don't really understand the Mathematica syntax because there aren't a lot of useful examples out there. What I have done:

```
(* Input: 4 Points*)
Array[sx, 4, 0];
Array[sy, 4, 0];

sx[0] = -1; 
sy[0] = 0;

sx[1] = 0;
sy[1] = 2;

sx[2] = 1;
sy[2] = 4;

sx[3] = 3;
sy[3] = 32;


P[x,0]:=sy[0];

P[x, k_] := 
  P[x, k - 1] + (sy[k] - P[sx[k], k - 1])*
    Sum[(x - sx[j])/sx[k] - sx[j], {j, 0, x}];
```

(I tried to implement the geometric mean but I failed because I can't even calculate the Sum.)

How can I implement the recursion correctly? (an the geometric mean)

Comment: (You want `Product` instead of `Sum`...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a function P like this :

```
P[x_, 0]  := sy[0] 
P[x_, k_] := P[x, k - 1] + (sy[k] - P[sx[k], k - 1])*
             Product[(x - sx[j])/(sx[k] - sx[j]), {j, 0, k - 1}] // Simplify
```

Setting values `sx` and `sy` as you defined above we get :

```
In[13]:= P[x, 1] 
Out[13]= 2 (1 + x)

In[14]:= P[x, 2]
Out[14]= 2 (1 + x)

In[15]:= P[x, 3]
Out[15]= 2 + x + x^3
```

Comment: You are welcome, the method works just as a toy model, but the preferred way of interpolation in Mathematica  is the method presented by Heike.

Answer (score 3):

Just as an aside, Mathematica has a built-in function `InterpolatingPolynomial`. Suppose `pts` is the list of points for which you want to find the polynomial, then `p[x, k]` could be written as

```
p[x_, k_] := InterpolatingPolynomial[pts[[;;k+1]] ,x]
```

For the example in the original post you would get

```
pts = {{-1, 0}, {0, 2}, {1, 4}, {3, 32}};

p[x, 0] // Simplify
p[x, 1] // Simplify
p[x, 2] // Simplify
p[x, 3] // Simplify

(* output
0
2 (1 + x)
2 (1 + x)
2 + x + x^3
*)
```